# Qtranslate shows (Language) before the post title when it has no translation

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I have posts that I don't need to translate the title, but QTranslate is showing (Português) before the titles when i'm seeing the English version of the website and this is annoying me a lot. Does anybody know hw to remove this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, just found the solution...

Inside the plugin folder, look for the file "qtranslate_core.php" and replace this line:

return "(".$q_config['language_name'][$q_config['default_language']].") ".qtrans_use($q_config['default_language'], $text, $show_available);

for this:

return qtrans_use($q_config['default_language'], $text, $show_available);

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is coming to this in 2017: there's now a config value within qtranslate_options.php - you have to set show_displayed_language_prefix to false.

Alas, the plugin writers haven't made this configurable within the admin area, so you still have to hack the plugin as far as I can tell.